# How can I count the duplicate property values of an object?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of emails in my object. Such as:

```
{
    email1: yada@gmail.com,
    email2: hada@gmail.com,
    email3: hada@gmail.com
}
```

I want to find the duplicate emails, count the duplicates values for each and then within another object, show the number of duplicate emails found for each email.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are all of the object properties email addresses? Please [edit] your question to show the desired output format. In your example there are no duplicates (given that "H" != "h").

Comment: Any output format which you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Input 

    var input = {
         email1: "yada@gmail.com",
         email2: "hada@gmail.com",
         email3: "hada@gmail.com"
        }

    var output = {};
    for (var key in input) {
        output[input[key]] = (output[input[key]] || 0) + 1;
    }

    for (var key in output) {
        if (output[key] > 1) {
            console.log(key, output[key]);
        }
    }
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/fiteqayibi/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Missing explanation

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = {
  email1: 'yada@gmail.com',
  email2: 'hada@gmail.com',
  email3: 'hada@gmail.com'
}

// first get a count of each:
var addressCount = Object.keys(input)     // get the keys of the object
  .map(function(k) { return input[k] })   // map to get an array of the addresses
  .reduce(function(acc, email) {          // reduce that array using an object
    acc[email] = (acc[email] || 0) + 1    // to keep totals for each distinct email
    return acc
  }, {})  
console.log(addressCount)

// then keep the ones with count > 1
var duplicates = Object.keys(addressCount)
  .reduce(function(acc, email) {
    if (addressCount[email] > 1)
      acc[email] = addressCount[email]
    return acc
  }, {})
console.log(duplicates)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: @Rajesh - My inclination is to provide explanation in proportion to the effort the OP seems to have made, but I guess I'll add some extra comments...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```js
function countEmails(emails) {
  return Object
    .keys(emails)
    .map(email => emails[email])
    .reduce((counter, email) => {
      return Object.assign({}, counter, {
        [email]: counter[email] ? (counter[email] + 1) : 1,
      });
    }, {});
}

const emails = {
  email1: 'asdf@asdf.asdf',
  email2: 'asdf@asdf.asdf',
  email3: 'qwer@qwer.qwer',
};

console.log(countEmails(emails)); // { 'asdf@asdf.asdf': 2, 'qwer@qwer.qwer': 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
var obj = {
  email1: 'yada @gmail.com',
  email2: 'hada @gmail.com',
  email3: 'hada @gmail.com'
}
var tempArray = []; // An array to track what is not duplicate
var newObj = {}  // It is new object without duplicate
for (var keys in obj) {
  // check in array if a key value is present
  if (tempArray.indexOf(obj[keys]) === -1) { 
    // if not present add in the array, so next time it wont add again
    tempArray.push(obj[keys]);
    // in new object create a relevant key and add it's value
    newObj[keys] = obj[keys]
  }
}
console.log(newObj)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/L323t46q/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- Create 2 objects,one for count and other for duplicates.
- Loop over emails and set values in `counts` with necessary value.
- If count is more than `1`, set its value in `dupes` as well.

```js
var input = {
  email1: 'yada@gmail.com',
  email2: 'hada@gmail.com',
  email3: 'hada@gmail.com'
}

var counts = {};
var dupes = {};

for(var k in input){
  var v = input[k];
  var count = (counts[v] || 0) + 1;
  counts[v] = count;
  if(count > 1)
    dupes[v] = count
}

console.log(counts, dupes)
```